# issue with DBMS_ADVISOR package

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, database-administration

I am trying to use the oracle SQL access advisor utility.

For recommendation on performance tuning and partitioning of tables.

But when i try to use it gives me no results and says there are no result for the task.

I am trying below code to generate the recommendation this is an example from SCOTT schema which also giving me same error

```
declare

    v_sql varchar2(2000) := 'select * from emp where empno in (7369,7499)';

    v_tuning_task varchar2(200) := 'tune_task_advisor_view7';

    v_tune_result clob;

begin



    dbms_advisor.quick_tune ( dbms_advisor.sqlaccess_advisor , v_tuning_task, v_sql );

    DBMS_ADVISOR.reset_task(v_tuning_task);

    dbms_advisor.set_task_parameter(v_tuning_task, 'ANALYSIS_SCOPE', 'ALL');

    dbms_advisor.set_task_parameter(v_tuning_task, 'STORAGE_CHANGE', '10000000');

    dbms_advisor.set_task_parameter ( v_tuning_task, 'MODE', 'COMPREHENSIVE');

    dbms_output.put_line ('Quick Tune Completed');

end;



SELECT DBMS_ADVISOR.get_task_script ('tune_task_advisor_view7') AS script FROM dual;
```

The Error --

```
SELECT DBMS_ADVISOR.get_task_script ('tune_task_advisor_view7') AS script FROM dual
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-13631: The most recent execution of task    tune_task_advisor_view7 contains no results.
ORA-06512: at "SYS.PRVT_ADVISOR", line 3350
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_ADVISOR", line 641
ORA-06512: at line 1
13631. 00000 -  "The most recent execution of task %s contains no results."
*Cause:    The user attempted to create a report or script from a task that
       has not successfully completed an execution.
*Action:   Execute the task and then retry the operation
```

There is one more that when i comment all the SET_TASK_PARAMETER procedure then it run but does not provide any recommendations the output is like --

```
SCRIPT                                                                      
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Rem  SQL Access Advisor: Version 11.2.0.3.0 -        Production                     
Rem                                                                             
Rem  Username:
```

Is there any parameter which i missed to define here.

For RESET_TASK if i do not rest_task then it gives me error for it also so i have used it here.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

When I get this error, this typically means that the DBMS_ADVISOR does not have any advise for the profile based on its diagnostic so it doesn't return a report.  I typically don't try to produce a ADDM advisor report, but rather look for all the HASH plans I can find for the query, run an explain plan on those hash values, and then profile the one with the best plan.

Comment: @Derek----Thanks for Reply but later i figure it out that i forgot to execute the task like .......execute dbms_advisor.execute_task('tune_task_advisor_view7'); and it starts working fine. BTW can you provide me any links for the suggestion that will help me producing HASH plans i want to look after your solutions also and i need to get a report where i can reach to a conclusion for partitioning of my table. My problem is to identify the tables in our environment for partitioning and then check the behavior of the environment after partitioning.

Comment: Great!  I'm glad you found the problem.  Here is the way I typically do this.  Look at the next answer I provided, as the comment section doesn't have enough space.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to execute the task !

```
exec dbms_advisor.execute_task('tune_task_advisor_view7');
```

and then

```
SELECT DBMS_ADVISOR.get_task_script ('tune_task_advisor_view7') AS script FROM 
dual;
```

OUTPUT will be

```
 SCRIPT
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Rem  SQL Access Advisor: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
Rem
Rem  Username:        CHRIS
Rem  Task:            tune_task_advisor_view7
Rem  Execution date:
Rem

/* RETAIN INDEX "SCOTT"."PK_EMP" */
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Find address and hash for the query SQL_ID

   select address, hash_value, plan_hash_value from v$sqlarea where sql_id = '3mx8whn1c5jbb';
2. Purge the plan out of the cursor cache (only if it’s determined that it’s the wrong plan). Statistics should be up to date prior to purging out the plan.

   exec sys.dbms_shared_pool.purge(',','C');

   exec sys.dbms_shared_pool.purge('00000005DF37F740,46318955','C');
3. Create the tuning plan if one does not exist.

   variable stmt_task VARCHAR2(64);

   SET SERVEROUTPUT ON LINESIZE 200 PAGESIZE 20000 LONG 9999

   EXEC :stmt_task := DBMS_SQLTUNE.CREATE_TUNING_TASK(sql_id => '3mx8whn1c5jbb',task_name => '3mx8whn1c5jbb_AWR_tuning_task');

   SELECT DBMS_SQLTUNE.REPORT_TUNING_TASK('3mx8whn1c5jbb_AWR_tuning_task', 'TEXT', 'TYPICAL', 'FINDINGS') FROM DUAL;
4. If the tuning plan is reported. Accept the new plan.

   DECLARE

   sqlprofile_name VARCHAR2(30);

   BEGIN

   sqlprofile_name := DBMS_SQLTUNE.ACCEPT_SQL_PROFILE (

   task_name => '3mx8whn1c5jbb_AWR_tuning_task'

   , name => 'sql_profile_1'

   , force_match => true

   );

   END;

   /
5. If creating a profile doesn’t work or if the plan does not exist in the cursor cache, check the AWR repository to see if a better plan exists.

If you have an AWR repository with the correct plan, you can rerun the queries above and just use the option to get the hash and sql_id from the AWR repository.

If that doesn't work. THEN I used ADDM (As you did above).

Comment: Great i'll try to use it.But now i ahve a bigger scenario which my manager expected from me to execute. He told me to look after all the SQL queries like SELECT ,UPDATE,DELETE,INSERT on the database when any order is fired by our application this will help us to track down that which queries are frequently being used and which tables are frequently being used after that we can come to an conclusion that which tables requires the partitioning, So do you have any idea that How can i get a trace report of all the SQL queries which gets fired on any activity(ex. fire a order) from the application?

Comment: Yes, there is definitely a way to do that.  It is typically done on the database side.  It's call application context tracing.  There are several ways to do this.  1)  DBA sets up tracing on a database for the session_id, sid of the application user: execute DBMS_SYSTEM.SET_SQL_TRACE_IN_SESSION(<serial#>,<sid>,TRUE); (check the syntax).  This will trace for that session. Or 2) use DBMS_MONITOR.  Which requires setting up calls inside the application or PL/SQL code.  execute DBMS_MONITOR.SERV_MOD_ACT_TRACE_ENABLE to start trace.  EXEC DBMS_MONITOR.SERV_MOD_ACT_TRACE_DISABLE to stop trace.

Comment: There are several other ways beyond what I mentioned above.  Let me know if you need more info.  We can start a new thread (if one doesn't already exists)

Comment: Thanks Derek i am starting New tread for this lets discuss it over there. Meanwhile i'll check the  DBMS_SYSTEM.SET_SQL_TRACE_IN_SESSION(<serial#>,<sid>,TRUE) use of it and how can i apply it in my scenario i will let you know the name of the thread when i create it. and also there is a VIEW V$SQL which records SQL's of last two months is this the same as we required above ?

Comment: I have created a NEW thread with the name as "tracing all SQL queries which have executed when application fire an order" and provided my full requirement there please check !